# Edit a SQL row with a html form that is already populated with the same row

Tags: php, html

Trying to edit a sql row with html form. I know that im vulnerable to sql-injection with the use of mysqli. But im fairly new to this. My goal is with a html button call a php function that updates the values of the row and then return to the page where the list is done. I learned that ajax is the best way but can't getting working.

edit.php

```
<?php
try
{
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=SCMMM; charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
}

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$nomeF = $_POST['nomeF'];    
$nomeL = $_POST['nomeL'];
$Prof = $_POST['Profissao'];
$morada = $_POST['morada'];
$cod = $_POST['cod'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$ordb = $_POST['ordb'];
$orde = $_POST['orde'];
$dataI = $_POST['dataI'];
$dataF = $_POST['dataF'];
$notas1 = $_POST['notas1'];
$notas2 = $_POST['notas2'];

$sql = "UPDATE Colaboradores SET (NomeF, NomeL, Profissao, Morada, CodPostal, Telemovel, mail, precoh, precohmais, dataI, dataF, notas1, notas2) 
  VALUES (:nomeF, :nomeL, :Prof, :morada, :cod, :num, :mail, :ordb, :orde, :dataI, :dataF, :notas1, :notas2) WHERE ColabID = $id";

       // get row number and insert into the table**
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('nomeF', $nomeF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('nomeL', $nomeL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('Prof', $Prof, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('morada', $morada, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('cod', $cod, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('ordb', $ordb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('orde', $orde, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('dataI', $dataI, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('dataF', $dataF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('notas1', $notas1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('notas2', $notas2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();   
    }
?>
```

editColab.php

```
<?php 

try
{
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=SCMMM; charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
}

include("edit.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Colaboradores WHERE ColabID = $id";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

?>
```

Part of the html form in the same page editColab.php

```
<form id="Novocolab" method="post">
<div class="S">
<label for="notas2"><b>Notas</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Introduzir Notas" name="notas2" value="<?php echo $row['notas2']?>">        
</div>              

<div class="S">
    <button class="button" type="submit" value="submit">Concluído</button>

    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>                                                      
            </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Says function edit() is not defined

Comment: There is no js function `edit` in your code. You cannot call a `PHP` function directly from `JS`

Comment: I thought since is inside a form the button could call a php function. So how do I do this.

Comment: Add the onsubmit attribute to the form tag:

Comment: Doesn't work, same error function edit is not defined

Comment: why are you using 2 different apis here, mysqli and PDO? You probably have a connection issue where one connects, then disconnects after calling the other api/methods.

Comment: Already change it to only PDO as u can see in the question, and still can't call the function edit, any others ideias?

Comment: Strongly suggest going back to basics - perhaps follow some tutorials. The main issue is encapsulated in @ClydeLobo's comment above. The web browser is never aware of php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS runs on the client browser, PHP runs on the server. When a page loads, the server first processes any PHP code on the page, then sends the page to the browser, which will parse the html/css and execute any JS that is set to run when the page finishes loading.

The form's target attribute needs to be set to the PHP script that you've shown us. This means that when the browser submits the form, it will send the form data to that PHP script, which will be able to read the $_POST data and process your update.

Comment: So if i separate the function 'edit' in a new script with 'if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")' and include this script where the form is, after i press the button submit it will update?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, yes that should work.

Comment: It didn't work, i updated the question so that u can see my changes

Comment: You need to set the target attribute on your <form> tag. That's what tells the browser where to submit the form to. So you should have target="editColab.php", assuming all these files are in the same directory.

Comment: Still doesn't work, simply opens a new page with the form with the previous value not the one i inserted.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is nothing for me to go on. You need to do some troubleshooting of your own; use var_dump or similar to print out variables during execution in your script to see if you're reaching the right parts of your code and what your variables are set to at that point.